# Why does my code thing deployed() is not a function?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, solidity, web3js, truffle

code:

```
 loadContract: async ()=>{
     //Create JS version of smart contract
     const todoList = await $.getJSON('TodoList.json')
     App.contracts.TodoList = TruffleContract(todoList)
     App.contracts.TodoList = web3.setProvider(new Web3.providers.HttpProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
 
 //getting values from blockchain
 App.todoList = await App.contracts.TodoList.deployed()
 console.log(todoList)
```

error:

> TypeError: App.contracts.TodoList.deployed is not a function

I am able to call TodoList.deployed() in the truffle dev environment but not in the JavaScript file. I am trying to to set all the data from the deployed smart contract to App.todoList so I can work with the values in the JavaScript file and render them to the HTML. I am completely stuck. When I `console.log(todolist)` I receive the JSON of the smart contract.

Here is my migrations file.

```
//need migration to update state of blockchain

const TodoList = artifacts.require("./TodoList.sol");

module.exports = function (deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(TodoList);
};
//run migration and deploy contract to blockchain
```

Comment: Why are you assigning `App.contracts.TodoList` twice with two different values?

Comment: From your example we can not see where `deployed()` should come from. Seems like you just never define it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar error while dealing with hardhat
I'm thinking the `.deployed()` function may be deprecated or removed

Try `.waitForDeployment()`

That made the error go away for me

Similarly, if you want to find out the contract address
then instead of using `<contractVariable_name>.address`

Use `<contractVariable_name>.target`

This should help you (and possibly any further readers)